# Error when launching the app for the second time on android 10

Tags: database, react-native, sqlite, expo, typeorm

I have an application in react native that uses typeorm to manage data storage, when I start the app in an emulator or compile it on a cell phone with **android 10** the local database starts normally, but I just need to reload the application or simply kill the application in the emulator and open it again because the bank already has an error in creating and synchronizing the tables.

For this app, react natively using expo and typeorm in the following versions:

```
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.5",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
"expo-sqlite": "^11.0.0",
"typeorm": "^0.3.12",
```

When I start the application with nothing saved in cache, the database opens normally in all applications, but I just have to reload or kill the application completely and open it again and the database cannot synchronize, this only in **android 10**, however on **android 11** and **12** that were tested, it works normally.

**Method responsible for validating and connecting the database** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e47ec.png)

**The error that happens after reloading or killing the application and opening it again** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVhzF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pls Report typeorm issue on https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues